# Need to parse a cell in the excel for a particular text and copy text next to it

Tags: excel, vba

I have a large blurb of excel data and I need to parse all cells in column M, looking for a string ‘Signature Algorithm’ and if found, need to copy the text next to it in a separate cell of a separate column.

For example cells in column M contain lot of text.

```
Sample text-
Common name: blast
Version:3
Signature algorithm: RSA with SHA-1
```

I need to look through all the data and if there is signature algorithm in the data, I need to copy the value RSA with SHA-1 into a separate cell.

Please help

Comment: whar did you try ? where is the error ? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

With a VBA UDF you can `Split()` your string by `Signature algorithm:` (case sensitive here) and pull the second element from the resulting array. Then to be safe, split that by `vbcrlf` (end of line) and return the first element:

```
Public Function getSignatureAlgorithm(inString As String) As String
    On Error Resume Next
    getSignatureAlgorithm = Split(Split(inString, "Signature algorithm: ")(1), vbCrLf)(0)
End Function
```

Just pop open your VBE, add a new module, and paste that in. Then you can use it in your worksheet. For instance if this value was in `Sheet1` cell `A1`, in `B2` you could write:

```
=getSignatureAlgorithm(A1)
```

And it will spit out:

```
RSA with SHA-1
```

Comment: Name error suggests that it's not seeing the UDF. Insure that it's a Module and the workbook has been saved. And it's been saved as a .xslm.

Comment: Actually, it worked like a charm. I had multiple workbooks open, that’s why it wasn’t working, as I was referencing another workbook. Thank you!!

Comment: Also- quick thing, how do I limit the characters for the output string? Since there is lot of data after RSA with SHA-1, the output comes out as huge string

Answer (score 3):

If this was our data

[image: image 1]

Then I used this formula in b2, then dragged it down to b3:
I used: =IFERROR(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("Signature algorithm",A1)),RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH("RSA",A1)+1),""),"")

[image: Image 2]

So to break it down, iferror , ", checks for error, provides "" if an error is found.
isnumber checks to see if there is a number.
Find searches for "Signature algorithm" in A1.
Right returns everything Right of the returned number.
Len is the character length of AI.
Search finds RSA.

So in total, we search for Signature algorithm, if it is found it returns a number. If it's a number, then they search for RSA. If RSA is found, it returns everything after and including RSA.

Comment: Thanks, the concern is that there might be different values other than RSA, I need to get the strong next to Sogmature algorithm.

Comment: If it is always "Signature algorithm: ", then I used the following to grab everything right of that expression. There may be a more elegant solution than this, but I hope this is what you need: =IFERROR(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("Signature algorithm",A1)),RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH("Signature algorithm",A1)-20),""),"")

Answer (score 0):

try this pleas:

```
Public Function getSigAlg(txt As String) As String

findIfAlgorithm = InStr(1, txt, "Signature algorithm")

If findIfAlgorithm > 0 Then
    getSigAlg = Left(Right(txt, (Len(txt) - (findIfAlgorithm + Len("Signature algorithm") + 1))), 14)
Else
    getSigAlg = "no Signature"
End If

End Function
```

**then in cell B1**

> =getSigAlg(A1)

[image]